# Watchdog monitoring for multi microcontroller - Embedded Systems

Tags: watchdog

I am using 3 micro-controller on a board. 
Main micro, gateway micro and safety micro;
name suggest the associated applications.

Internal watchdog exist for all three, but I need to have an external supervision so as not to have a buggy timer code nullifying the effect of internal watchdog. Also to keep the BOM cost low, so can use just 1 external watchdog.

Propose to use the following strategy:

1. Main microcontroller: We plan to have the internal watchdog and as well an external watchdog for this.
2. Safety Microcontroller: We plan to have internal watchdog and as well monitoring over SPI by Main microcontroller.
3. Gateway Microcontroller:  We plan to have internal watchdog and as well monitoring over SPI by Main microcontroller.

One issue with this is - **EMI or noise issues over line causing SPI corruption** and hence false RESET from main micro.

Has anybody faced similar challenge? Any suggestions for this?

Many Thanks for your help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the specifics of your application, it is not possible to give you a definitive answer. The way you would normally solve this sort of problem is to do a failure mode and effects analysis. Essentially you list out all the parts of your system and then brainstorm all the possible failure modes you think could happen. EMC would be one of them. You then estimate a probability that each failure mode will occur and assign a severity to it in the event that it does occur. Multiplying these out will allow you to identify the areas that carry greater impact and need extra protection. When all the failure modes have a severity x risk value below a threshold set by your application, you will have a 'valid' solution.

Not doing a thorough analysis like this means you may very well put all your effort into defending the front door while leaving the back door unlocked.